# PERL regex matching lines containing certain directory path

Tags: regex, perl

What is the best way to use regular expression in Perl for filtering all lines containing, for instance `/usr/libexec/postfix`?

That would also catch, e.g.: `/usr/libexec/postfix/qmgr`, `/usr/libexec/postfix/smtp`, `/usr/libexec/postfix/local` and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
if ($line =~ m{^/usr/libexec/postfix.*}) {
     print "Match!\n";
} else {
     print "No match\n";
}
```

Working example:
http://codepad.org/jkVlISdv

Comment: The `.*` is superfluous in this case

Comment: `.*` in `m{^/usr/libexec/postfix.*}` is not necessary and it may slow the matching a bit?

Comment: True. But it will come handy when you need to capture it in separate group like this: `my ($path, $suffix) = ($line =~ m{^(/usr/libexec/postfix)(.*)});`. I don't think you will be able to measure speed difference it for single line.

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thank you very much. `.*` isn't really necessary in this case. It works as expected. Example: http://codepad.org/jkVlISdv